# create multiple tables using loop in sql

Tags: sql-server

I would like to create multiple tables with same column names. The name of the tables would be table1, table2, table3, etc. Can someone help me correct the part 'table@cnt' in codeline 4?.

```
declare @cnt int = 0;
while @cnt < 7
begin 

CREATE TABLE table@cnt(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)   
);

set @cnt = @cnt + 1;
end;
```

Comment: use dynamic sql with exec() i.e. 'CREATE TABLE table' + convert(varchar(10), @cnt) + '(
PersonID int,'

Comment: @artm thank you for your prompt help. can you please elaborate more?

Comment: my problem still not solved. please help.

Comment: As artm mentioned, you'd replace `CREATE TABLE table@cnt(PersonID int...);` with `EXEC('CREATE TABLE table' + convert(varchar(10), @cnt) + '(PersonID int...);');`

Comment: @Sonam Please try to search  .... You had keyword `dynamic sql` from @artm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @cnt int = 0;
while @cnt < 7
begin 

declare @q nvarchar(max) = 'CREATE TABLE table' + convert(varchar(10), @cnt) + '(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)   
);'

exec (@q)

set @cnt = @cnt + 1;
end;
```

Comment: it worked like a magic. thanks a lot for your help. have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamic query like this

```
DECLARE @cnt int = 1
DECLARE @TableName varchar(20) = CAST(@cnt as varchar(20))

DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = 
                   N'CREATE TABLE '+  @TableName + 
                   ' (
                   PersonID int,
                   LastName varchar(255),
                   FirstName varchar(255),
                   Address varchar(255),
                   City varchar(255)   
                   )'
EXEC (@query)
```

Comment: The above throws error Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table'.

Comment: But it will creates only One table it deosn't loop over as tab1 ,tab2  ...

Comment: You could use it  with `WHILE ...` in OP's post.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @cnt int = 1
While(@cnt <=10)
Begin
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = 
                   N'CREATE TABLE '+'table_'+CASt(@cnt  AS VARCHAR(10))+
                   ' (
                   PersonID int,
                   LastName varchar(255),
                   FirstName varchar(255),
                   Address varchar(255),
                   City varchar(255)   
                   )'

EXEC (@query)
SET @cnt=@cnt+1
END
```